# slight vs marginal vs little vs incremental vs insignificant vs moderate

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I have come across the following words and to me they all mean the same. Can someone elaborate on their use cases and which one to use when?

- slight
- marginal
- little
- incremental
- insignificant
- moderate

An example of one of them is, "The contributions of the above work is only *incremental*."

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked up all these words in a dictionary? Your example doesn't make sense, because _incremental_ means increasing by small amounts rather than gradually. Also, _moderate_ means to a greater degree than _slight_.

Comment: Please look at the comment added to @JavaLatte answer below. If you could help me on that? In the dictionary I found it hard to compare these words and the answer given below definitely helps me much more than reading the definition of these words in isolation.

Comment: On this board, we like you to say what effort you have made to find out the answer for yourself, and what it is you still don't understand. Those four words are _more or less_  equivalent, but to call something _insignificant_ is rather negative - 'not worth bothering about'. So, you could say that a sick person has made _a slight improvement_, but it would sound rather odd to say _an insignificant improvement_.

Comment: `On this board, we like you to say what effort you have made to find out the answer for yourself, and what it is you still don't understand.` Thank you for the clarification on the proper use of this forum. I shall definitely not be lazy from next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some of these words, it helps if you think about what the words actually mean.

A margin is the edge of something- for example, the margins on a printed document are the whitespace around the actual text. So something that is [marginal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/marginal) means a) that it's quite a small amount compared to the whole, and/or b) that it's outside the main area of interest.

> The weather had a marginal effect on the event

[Insignificant](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/insignificant) describes something that does not signify - it has no meaning in the overall situation.

> John's contribution to this project was insignificant.

An increment is something added on... so [incremental](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/incremental) refers to something added on to the existing situation. it is normally used to refer to something that is added or improved in a series of small stages (increments). It doesn't really fit in with the other words.

> The incremental effect of each breakdown in the factory adds up to a major loss of production.

[Moderate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/moderate) means medium, unlike all of the other words that refer to small things.

[slight](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slight) and [little](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/little) both simply refer to a small amount of something. Little, is generally only used as an adjective in informal situations, though it's OK to use it as a determiner in formal situations.

> I found this little flower in the garden - *informal*
> This news makes little difference to our situation - *formal*

Comment: So if I visualize each of these words in terms of *quantity*, then is the following order correct in ascending order. Insignificant>Marginal>Little>Incremental>Moderate? Or is it Insignificant>Marginal>Incremental>Little>Moderate? For eg, if A contribution is more than B in a project I would use *marginal* for B and *moderate* for A.

Comment: Not at all. The magnitudes of slight, insignificant, marginal and little (ie small) are probably similar, but as I explained, the point that you are making about the size is different. Moderate is medium.  Incremental has a different meaning.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification. But if you could help me a bit more. `The magnitudes of slight, insignificant, marginal and little (ie small) are probably similar`. So in effect, I can use *slight, insignificant, marginal, and little* interchangeably?

Comment: NO, YOU CANNOT! They are not interchangeable. Let me say this again. The **degrees** are similar, but **the point that you are making** is different. If you don't understand the differences, just use **slight**, which does not make a specific point.